# Underline <a> tag with React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I was Wondering how to give style to two  tags in react without using the className(as not using className is the main challenge).

```
<a href="">Menu Here</a>
<a href="">Click Me </a>
```

[image]

So for the "curry dish," it should only underline when hovering.
And for the click me it should be underlined first and disappear while hovering on it.
I got both underlines removed using the code below. But still can't figure out how to apply separate styling please help.

```
a: hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
**Tags in react without using the className:**

<span style={{color: "red",cursor: "pointer",
text-decoration: underline !important }}> 
<a href="">Menu Here</a>

</span>
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea of span. Although how do I make only underlined when hovering?
The text should not be underlined unless we hover over it.

Comment: This answer is not using json. Json and css are two completely different syntaxes.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using CSS you can do this with a simple stateful react component.

```
const UnderlineHover = ({children, ...rest}) => {
  const [isHover, setIsHover] = useState(false);

  const style = isHover ? {textDecoration: "underline"} : {};

  return <a onMouseEnter={() => setIsHover(true)}
    onMouseLeave={() => setIsHover(false)}
    style={...style}
    {...rest}
  >{children}</a>;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try with state and style like=>

```
const [hover,setHover] = useState("")
const handleMouseEnter =()=>{
setHover(true)
}
const handleMouseExit =()=>{
setHover(false)
}
const linkStyle = {
text-decoration: hover? underline:none;
}
return(
<a href="" style={linkStyle} onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter} onMouseLeave={handleMouseExit}>Menu Here</a>
<a href="" style={linkStyle} onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter} onMouseLeave={handleMouseExit}>Click Me </a>
)
```

Hope this will help to solve out your problem. If you still facing issue just lemme know, i will help you more.
Thanks